# Composition and inheritance design problem

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I got these virtual classes from a library that implement an algorithm in the form of abstract classes

```
class A{
    public : 
    virtual void foo() = 0 ;
};


class B{
    public:
        void setA(A * a) { m_a = a ;}

        virtual void f() = 0;
        void g() {m_a->foo();}
    protected:
        A * m_a ;
 };
```

To use the library you just have to derive the classes and implement the pure virtual functions, like `foo()`, and provide other methods specific to the implementation as well (`bar()`).

```
class dA : public A {
    public :
         void foo() {/* ... */}
         void bar() {/* ... */}
};

class dB : public B {
     public :
          void f() ;
};
```

I would typically use these class by calling

```
dB * mydB = new dB() ;
mydB->setA(new dA() );
mydB->f() ;
mydB->g() ;
```

But I have a design problem when implementing `dB::f()`, because I need to call `dA::bar()` which is specific to `dB`. But in the class, I only keep a reference to dB trough a B*. Then I have thought of two options :

- use a `dynamic_cast` each time `f()`is called to cast `B::m_a` into a `dB*`
- add a m_dA member to dB which stores the same pointer as m_a, but can be used to access dB specific functions.

Of course I can't change the the base classes.

I would like to know if there is a more elegant solution to this problem (like a design pattern I did not thought of). If not, which one should I choose ?

Comment: If `bar()` gets called a lot I'd just go with the second option you've listed.

Comment: The Visitor Pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) may be of use to you. It's hard to give concrete recommendations with such an abstract description of your problem.

Comment: Public inheritance might not be the right solution here in the first place... `dB` places restrictions on its use that do not exist in `B`, so an instance of `dB` can not be safely treated as a `B`.

Comment: @Dennis : would that be a case where private inheritance can be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've a third solution. Add a function `setA()` in the `dB`. Of course, this function will hide `B::setA()` which is good for you if `dB::setA()` is implemeted as:

```
class dB : public B 
{
     dA *m_dA ; //add this member also!
     public :
          void f()
          {
             m_dA->bar(); //fast forward : no cast here!
          }
          void setA(A *a) //this hides B::setA()
          {
             m_dA= dynamic_cast<dA*>(a); //just one time dynamic cast!
             if ( m_dA == 0 )
             {  
                 throw std::runtime_error("invalid argument");
             }
             B::setA(a); //now call the hidden function in the base!
          }
};
```

In this way, you don't need to dynamic_cast each time you call `dB::f()`, which makes the call fast!

Comment: But if you have a `B* b = new dB;` and call `b->setA(new dA);`, the wrong function will be called, and `db::m_dA` will not be updated properly.

Comment: @Dennis: In that case, you've to call the function as `dynamic_cast<dB*>(b)->setA(new dA);`

Comment: @Dennis: Yeah I realized that, and so edited my comment.Read it again.

Answer (score 1):

`dB` as a concrete class should not call methods on `dA` an unrelated concrete class. Even with `reinterpret_cast` this is bad design which couples the unrelated objects uneccessarily. The common functionality should be put in a common base class or interface.

For example class `A` can be considered an interface as it has nothing but pure virtual methods. Therefore it would be safe to use multiple inheritance if you wanted that interface on `dB` as well. You of course would then have to implement your own `foo` in that case.

```
class dB : public B, public A {
     public :
          void f();
          void foo();
};
```

If `bar()` is the one you want and for some reason you can change the interface `A` then make your own interface which provides a pure virtual function `bar()` and then make both `dA` and `dB` inherit from your new interface and implement `bar()` accordingly and use interface pointers to that.

If you must use one in terms of the other then composition is the way to go but not of the ambiguous base pointer which may fail a dynamic cast. Make a concrete `dA` member within `dB` perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your dB can only work if the A it has is actually a dA. You need to make sure that this is always the case.

Hence over-ride the setA method to use a dynamic_cast to check that it really is a dA. Now whether you then at that point save the result in m_dA or dynamic cast again later is unimportant. There's less possibility of having an incorrectly initialised dB, whose dynamic cast may fail later.